# How do I prove that an inner product has a bijection $ w \rightarrow f$

Tags: inner-products

Let

$\mathcal{H} = \{f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R} : \exists w \in \mathbb{R^d}, f(x) = \langle w,x \rangle_{\mathbb{R}^d}, \forall x \in X \} $

where $\langle \cdot , \cdot \rangle$ denotes inner product.

How do you prove that $ w \rightarrow f$ is bijective?

I know that this might be a very simple question for people with more math experience than me, but have patience, I don't know how to do this.

I did try proof by contradiction, assume that there exists $f'(x) = \langle w', x\rangle$ and $f(x) = \langle w, x\rangle$ such that $f(x) =  f'(x)$ but $w \neq w'$. But I just got some empty equations that didn't lead me anywhere:

$f'(x) = \langle w', x\rangle$

$f(x) = \langle w, x\rangle$

$\langle f, f'\rangle = \langle w, w'\rangle$

$\langle f(x), f'(x)\rangle = \langle \langle w', x\rangle, \langle w, x\rangle\rangle$

I do know that the inner product is symmetric, linear and positive-definite. Not sure if that helps though... any ideas?

I think I even came up with a counter example for the special case of the "normal" dot product:

$\langle0.25, 0.75 \rangle \cdot \langle 2, 2 \rangle =  \langle 0.75, 0.25 \rangle \cdot \langle 2, 2 \rangle $

but $\langle0.25, 0.75 \rangle \neq \langle 0.75, 0.25 \rangle$

Why is my counter example invalid?

### ----

I am also not sure what is an appropriate tag for this Question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f(x) = f'(x)$ i.e.$\langle \omega, x\rangle = \langle \omega', x\rangle$ for all $x$, then $$\langle \omega - \omega', x\rangle = 0$$ for all $x$.

Then take $x= \omega - \omega'$, we get $$\langle \omega - \omega', \omega - \omega'\rangle = 0$$

which means $\omega - \omega' = 0$, i.e. $\omega  = \omega'$

Comment: wait, I have a question. If $\langle w, x\rangle = \langle w', x\rangle$, then $\langle w, x\rangle - \langle w', x\rangle = 0$. Which implies (by linearity) $\langle w - w', x - x\rangle = \langle w - w', 0 \rangle = 0$. I don't know how you got that $\langle w - w', x\rangle = 0$ for all x (i.e your starting line).

Comment: @Pinocchio The first version you write is correct, because $\langle x, z \rangle - \langle y, z \rangle = \langle x-y, z \rangle$

Comment: That makes sense to me. Thank you! :D

Comment: Sorry if this is a really late question, but if $\langle w -w', w-w' \rangle = 0$, then why does it mean $w-w' = 0$. I guess in general, why is it that if $\langle a, a \rangle = 0$, then $a = 0$? How does the definition of the inner product imply that?

Comment: @Pinocchio this is one part of the definition of inner product, see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space)

Comment: thanks! Sorry I guess I forgot that detail after re-reading your answer a month later. I guess the definition was not fresh in my head as it was back then. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: awesome, its because of positive-definitness. :)

Comment: What about surjective?

Comment: @StevenGregory that's by definition of $\mathcal{H}$